# Extending models in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I'm trying to do on the surface seems simple, basic OOP PHP but I just can't get it working. I have a controller class which is calling a model, that model extends another model of mine but it throws an error saying it can't find it:

Controller (Welcome.php):

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->users_model->getAll();
}
```

Users Model (User_model.php):

```
class Users_model extends Base_model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Base Model (Base_model.php):

```
class Base_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getAll($table)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('Query here');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `Fatal error: Class 'base_model' not found in /ci/application/models/Users_model.php on line 3`

Answer (score 2):

Save your `Base_model` in `application/core` named as `Base_model.php` with following code.

```
class Base_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getAll($table=FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('Query here');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Save `User_model` in `application/models` named as `User_model.php` having following code

```
class User_model extends Base_model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Then make a controller `Welcome.php` in `appliation/controllers` having following code with extending `CI_Controller`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');//loads user_model
}

public function index()
{
    $data = $this->user_model->getAll(); //need a variable to hold return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to locate the Base_model in your Users_model like below code and you can access the functions of base model easily.

```
require('application/models/base_model.php');

class User_model extends Base_model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```